# How to reuse superclass method's variables in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I want to subclass by extending a method that always has the same first stage, say:

```
class Data:
    def show(self):
    #  this part is common for all subclasses
        total=10

class PrintA(Data):
    def show(self):
        Data.show(self)
        print(total)

class PrintAPlus(Data):
    def show(self):
        Data.show(self)
        print(total+10)
```

However, I get `NameError: name a is not defined`.

How to reuse `total` variable from the superclass's method?
(The obvious one is to save it as instance's attribute, but I don't need there, actually.)

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: *The obvious one is to save it as instance's attribute*  <--  yep, that's it.  Or you could return it from the parent method, and use that return value.

Comment: if you don't want `total` as a public attribute, you may define it as private with `_` preceding it. But the right way to do this by defining `total` as attribute (whether public or private is upto you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem here is that `total` is only assigned inside the superclass method `show`, there is just a local variable. its value can't be see outside it.

to fix it you need to make it a instance attribute or return that value from there

option 1

```
class Data:
    def show(self):
    #  this part is common for all subclasses
        self.total = 10

class PrintA(Data):
    def show(self):
        Data.show(self)
        print(self.total)

class PrintAPlus(Data):
    def show(self):
        Data.show(self)
        print(self.total+10)
```

option 2

```
class Data:
    def show(self):
    #  this part is common for all subclasses
        return 10

class PrintA(Data):
    def show(self):
        total = Data.show(self)
        print(total)

class PrintAPlus(Data):
    def show(self):
        total = Data.show(self)
        print(total+10)
```

Comment: That is, the parent's method and its extension do not have the same scope?

Comment: @homocomputeris no, each one have its own scope